# Circuitikz - IC circuit with relative coordinates

Tags: nodes, circuitikz, coordinates

I've represented an IC circuit using circuitikz, but it's a bit too rough to what I prefer. In particular I would like to use relative coordinates in this case and connect them to the ``IC device'' so that I don't have to guess where to place components. I would also like to scale the figure and maintain the integrity of the circuit. (Remove scale = 1.4 to get the unbroken circuit)

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,american]{circuitikz} 


\begin{document}
%----IC device: 555 astable timer, or square wave oscillator
\tikzstyle{icdev}=[draw, text width=6em, minimum height=8em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {font = \footnotesize},scale = 1.4]
    \draw (0,4)
    to[short,o-] (0.8,4)
    to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm,R] (0.8,2.4)
    to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm,R] (0.8,1.8)
    to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm,C] (0.8,0.2) -- (0.8,0)
    to[short,-o] (0,0);
    \node (digichip) [icdev,xshift=3cm,yshift=2cm] {};
% top terminal pins - 4 RESET, 8 Vcc
    \path [draw](0.8,4) -| (2.5,3.4) node[below]{RESET} node[above left]{4};
    \path [draw](2.5,4) -| (3.5,3.4) node[below]{$V_{cc}$} node[above left] {8};
% bottom terminal pins - 1 GND  , 5 CTRL
    \path [draw](0.8,0) -| (2.5,0.6) node[above]{GND} node[below left]{1};
    \path [draw](2.5,0) -- (3.5,0)
        to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm,C](3.5,0.6)  
        node[above]{CTRL} node[below left]{5};
% leftside terminal pins - 7 DIS, 6 THR, 2 TRG
    \draw (0.8,2.6) -- (1.83,2.6) node[right]{DIS} node[above left]{7}
        (1.2,1.5) |- (1.83,2) node[right]{THR} node[above left]{6}
        (0.8,1.5) -- (1.83,1.5) node[right]{TRG} node[above left]{2};
% rightside terminal pin - 3 out
    \draw (4.17,2) node[left]{Out} -- (4.8,2) node[above left]{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: IC device - bad/good]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the scale problem, use `[scale=1.4,transform shape]` instead of `[scale=]`
for the other item, not enough experience